# In rails, given an array of objects, how can I output a CSV list instead of to_json?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I do:

```
Contact.select('email').first(1000).to_json
```

I get a JSON response with emails... How can I get just a CSV of emails? XXX@.com, XXX@.com

I'm trying to do this from rails console.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Contact.select('email').map(&:email).join(", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install [this plugin](https://github.com/arydjmal/to_csv) to have the `to_csv` method. Or you can implement it yourself.

I would vote for the prior, because if you'll need to print out names instead of emails you should implement the escaping as well, and this would be there for you by the plugin.

*Update:*

Oh I have not realized that you need only the mails, with this plugin you could do the following:

```
@emails = Contact.select('email').first(1000).map(&:email)

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml { render :xml => @emails }
  format.csv { send_data @emails.to_csv }
end
```